# Assembly being optimized out of build

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, visual-studio-2013, .net-assembly

I have an assembly entirely filled with classes that are implementing interfaces in another assembly. For instance:

```
Main Assembly (Reference to both assemblies)

Shared Assembly
-----IModule 

Class Assembly (Reference to shared assembly)
-----unknownType : IModule
-----unknownType2 : IModule
```

The Main assembly has no direct reference to any of the types in the Class assembly. I am looking for the types like so:

```
// Load all referenced assemblies:
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()
    .Except(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Select(a => a.GetName()))
    .Distinct()
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(act => Assembly.Load(act));

// Find all instances of IModule in loaded assemblies:
var modules = from asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
   from provider in asm.GetTypes()
   where typeof(IModule).IsAssignableFrom(provider)
   ...instantiate type etc...
```

If I have a reference to just an arbitrary type in the Class Assembly, then it shows up in GetReferencedAssemblies, gets loaded, and returned correctly - but as soon as i remove the reference to the type, it does not get transferred to the build directory or show up as a referenced assembly causing the load to fail.

Is there any way to force VS to include this assembly in the output directory? The main application should have no knowledge of any of the types within the class assembly.

Comment: I remember having a similar issue, and the only solution I found was to add a dummy call to the referenced assemblies in the project...

Comment: @KevinD: Since the main assembly is not supposed to know what goes on in the class assembly, i can't realistically add a dummy reference unless i enfore that a type in class assembly is created specifically for that purpose. The problem is that the example here is over simplified and doing so would add unnecessary complication and mud to the design.

Comment: Is this a solution-specific issue or can you provide steps to reproduce it in arbitrary context?

Comment: You can add a post-build action on the "implementation" assembly to have it manually copied to the main assembly's bin folder. I had to do something similar once to get [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx) to work properly for similar reasons.

Comment: I presume you are trying to inject the implementation at runtime rather than referencing them at compile time?  We achieved that by loading all binaries in a given directory and registering the implementations against their required interfaces.  Then your Main assembly can use a post build step to copy the required implementations into the bin dir.

Comment: @Ruskin: You're correct in your assumption - but you are missing the point of the question. The question is, that when the code in implementation assembly is not directly used, VS will not automatically copy the assembly to the output directory - even though it is included in referenced assemblies.

Comment: This is the kind of situation where I think people mixes application development and installer development. Surely this is a deployment issue so it should be handled in the installer. Having said that adding some script to the postbuild event should do the job.

Answer (score -1):

I think I get your problem, but can you clarify your question? Are you expecting an assembly that you've added as a reference to your project to be copied to your output folder with your application? How did you add the reference? Is it a .dll or .exe that you browsed to in a file dialog, or is it a COM or GAC assembly that you picked from a list in the Add References dialog?

If you browsed to it, and it's not in the GAC directory, this kind of optimization is expected. Select your reference in the Solution Explorer, and make sure "Copy Local" in the properties window is set to true. You might try toggling this setting, even if it is. Your .vsproj file might just need to be rebuilt to include the reference.

If you're trying to reference a .dll from a file name stored in a string, or selected at runtime, then Visual Studio will have no way of knowing that your application is using it, nonetheless to copy it to your output directory. It shouldn't be too hard to do that with File.Copy, though, if you have the path of the .dll.

Comment: Clearly the people that commented on the original post have a better understanding of the question and have provided better answers. I'm expecting an assembly that is added as a project dependency (reference) to get copied to the output directory even if there are no direct usages of the code. Visual studio will see that no types are directly used and will not copy the referenced assembly to the output directory. The question is about how to prevent this optimization behavior.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying. There wasn't a question mark in your question, so I was kinda taking a stab at which of your statements you wanted an answer for. Have you tried opening the .csproj file in the solution directory and checking the dependencies there? I had similar problems with image and icon resources not being included in VS 2008, and the solution then was to remove a line that explicity prevented the reference from being read, so the Copy Local setting wasn't being read. Out of curiosity, why are you wanting to only reference the assembly dynamically, and not by name in code?